# Covariance of products of dependent random variables

Tags: random-variables, covariance

Given random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $Cov(X, Y) = c$, is it true that

$Cov(X, XY) \leq Cov(X, X)$

?

Comment: You can improve this Question by adding context, such as why the problem interests you or what approach you took to trying to solve it yourself.  If all else fails you could show the results of considering a fairly easy example, which would help convince Readers of your degree of interest and level of insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X\sim N(0,1), Y=X^{2}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for the answer